# Use Spotipy (python to acquire data) to gather the catalogues of Spotify Musics

Tags: python, spotipy

I would like to gather the data from Spotify by python package Spotipy.

After following the instructure from Spotify developer page, I got the API (two codes) however, when I type all the code (which in from instruction 
http://spotipy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/highlight=spotipy.util.prompt_for_user_token#ids-uris-and-urls
I log into the page that shows 404 not fund page. 
I checked my account, I believe that I have been used Spotify for a long time, I am sure that Spotify supposes record my music preference.

Thus, What should I do ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you post the simplest example of your code use? We will be able to help you better, it is commonly called [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Your link is a 404, where are the instructions supposed to be?

Comment: After typing all the code of Spotipy, it will us into account confirmation page.
https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/using-scopes/. 
After you confirm your account, (which means click the button " OK " )

Comment: it drive to the page shows 404. I am sure that my internet works well.

Comment: So basically you want to scrape the whole spotify catalogue ? I'm fairly certain that goes against their terms of use https://developer.spotify.com/developer-terms-of-use/